# Mariadb Docker container, unable to run mutiple statements

Tags: docker, mariadb

I'm building a MariaDB server in a Docker container using docker-compose up. I want the container to create several tables when it starts, so I've added my SQL script to my entrypoint.

However, I've found that my SQL script only works if it contains a single statement. If I try to create multiple tables or execute more than one statement, the script fails to create the tables.

What am I missing? How can I modify my entrypoint script to create multiple tables in the container when it starts?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

here is my test sql file

```
    CREATE TABLE pleaseWork (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE pleaseWork2 (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

Comment: You are missing, that it would be a lot easier to help if you showed some code ...

Comment: And you are executing that file how?

Comment: Use a `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` volume containing this SQL file per [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--init-file` flag provided by the mariadb, this flag takes in an sql file that runs when the database is initialized. An example is already given on the [MariaDB official dockerhub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) under the heading **How to reset root and user passwords** at the end.

```
docker run --rm mariadb:latest --init-file=/path/to/data.sql
```

Comment: Your link is broken...

Comment: @derpirscher just updated the answer.